# Give my website users access to my company's Google Drive

Tags: django, google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing an application in django and I need that the users who enter my website have access to  my company's Google Drive (normal account
) , I am trying to save the google accesses in the user's session, but it does not work

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

request.session['credentials'] = {'token': credentials.token,
  'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
  'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
  'client_id': credentials.client_id,
  'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
  'scopes': credentials.scopes
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to give users access to your google drive?  What if they upload a virus what if the spam your account and get you locked out.

Comment: My guess is that this doesn't work because you're trying to give all users access via the same token (at least, that's what it looks like, from your code), and Google is smart enough to tell that multiple people are trying to access using the same token. You may want to look into Drive's [Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions).

Comment: Can you disclose a bit more about what you are trying to do? Maybe there is some workaround I can offer you. Why do you need users to have access to your Drive? Doesn't this present a security risk for you?

Comment: Excuse me, I already edited the question, it is not my personal Google Drive, it is my company's, I think you are absolutely right.

Comment: I still do not understand the set up you have or the process you want the users to go through. Do you want them to go to a website and ask for access to a drive folder? Do they sign into the website?